# For R, how do I row bind an unknown number of items in list?

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I am new to R. I have many csv files that I want to append into a single CSV file.

I have the following issues in my below code:

1. After the 3rd line
   **Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
   argument "file" is missing, with no default****
2. I don't know the number of files in the folder to rowbind. So how do I amend this line of code to rowbind an unknown number of files?
   ****bind_rows(tables [1], tables [2], tables[3])****

Thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/...",pattern="*.csv", full.names = T)
tables <- lapply(files, read.csv(header=False))
merged <- bind_rows(tables [1], tables [2], tables[3])
write.csv(merged, file = "C:/.../files_merged.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: `bind_rows` accepts a list, `merged <- bind_rows(tables)` will bind the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax issues in the code. Try this :

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/...",pattern="*.csv", full.names = T)
tables <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read.csv, header=FALSE))
#A bit shorter
#tables <- purrr::map_df(files, read.csv, header=FALSE)
write.csv(tables, file = "C:/.../files_merged.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```